# Could not find an answer in any websites

Tags: plot, aesthetics

I have a time series from 2010Q1 to 2019Q4 built using ts(). I am unable to do a graph in ggplot2 to show year and relevant quarters in the x-axis (like 2010Q1,…, etc) for one of the variables, say A. The problem is the “aes” function: which throws up all kinds of error messages (a real nightmare for a non-programmer). I have checked previous postings and solutions, but none of them relate to “quarters”. Please help to do the 3-4 code lines required for this. I will be very grateful.

Comment: Welcome to SO. By “aes” function do you mean Advanced Encryption Standardd? or something specific to your code?

Comment: Sorry: I do not understand the question. All that I am trying to do - build a simple graph for a time series. I do not know how to do it. The aes process gets in the way. I read plenty of stuff on aes. Unfortunately, none of the examples I tried helped. Hence my request for help from someone who knows the stuff.

Comment: The "aes" is a cryptographic algorithm. So I'm assuming it is not related to graphs. You should remove that tag.

Comment: By "aes" I meant the so-called "aesthetics" in ggploot. fjsv does not seem to have read my question? Is my question not clear?

Comment: I read it clearly. If you check your tags and read them, the tag "aes" is related to cryptography and not "aesthetics" in ggploot. Please fix that.

Comment: I do not know how to remove this tag. What I meant by "aes" was the "aesthetics" mentioned in ggplot2 literature. I thought I stated rather clearly my problem. Raising issues about "tags" misses the point.

Comment: The question about tags is just because people search for them. Using the right tag will raise the visibility of your question and improve greatly the chances of finding someone that is able to answer you. I think in your case you should use the tag: "aesthetics". Regarding the tags, bellow your question you have the `edit` option. You can edit your question and update the tags. Hope this helps you.

Comment: In case my question is not clear. I am trying to do a simple time series plot. I have a problem in formatting the x-axis to show year and quarter (like 2010Q1 etc). From what I read, apparently one has to use something like aes(x=?????, y=somevariable) among specification of other geom-points etc, etc. I was looking for someone to help me with that formatting of the x-axis part in this case (because I get errors doing that).. Hope someone can help.